# How to format this number in fortran

Tags: format

Please tell me the format to read this number:

```
<9270173328.404339>
```

I tried with:

```
read (18,'(I11,F18.6)')
```

But the error showing

> Fortran runtime error: Value overflowed during integer read

Please help me